# How to detach Python child process on Windows (without setsid)?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi

I'm migrating some process code to Windows which worked well on Posix. Very simply put: the code to launch a subprocess and immediately detach will not work because `setsid()` is not available:

```
import os, subprocess, sys
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c', "print 'hello'"], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

I can remove the use of `setsid` but then the child process ends when the parent ends.

My question is **how do I achieve the same effect as `setsid` on Windows so that the child process lifetime is independent of the parent's?**

I'd be willing to use a particular Python package if one exists for this sort of thing. I'm already using `psutil` for example but I didn't see anything in it that could help me.

Comment: in windows child process lifetime independent of the parent. it not "attached" to parent.

Answer (score 5):

RbMn's comment on my question is in fact the answer. There is no need to detach because processes in Windows are always top-level objects. I tried this out with a sleeper task and it worked fine.

**However** as eryksun pointed out in the comments here, closing the console window WILL cause the child process to terminate. I also had some stability issues with Waitress and Popen on Windows that I *think* I've worked through by adding the following bit of code which sets some [process creation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-creation-flags) and uses `close_fds`:

```
if 'nt' == os.name:
     flags = 0
     flags |= 0x00000008  # DETACHED_PROCESS
     flags |= 0x00000200  # CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
     flags |= 0x08000000  # CREATE_NO_WINDOW

     pkwargs = {
         'close_fds': True,  # close stdin/stdout/stderr on child
         'creationflags': flags,
     }

 p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c', cmd], **pkwargs)
```

Comment: Yes and no. By default a process inherits the process group of its parent. The group ID is used to send console `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to processes that belong to a group.  Also, when a console is closed, all processes attached to it get a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` warning and will be forcefully terminated after 5 seconds. Since one process is marked as the effective owner of the console window (usually the allocating process), then killing the owner via taskill.exe or Task Manager sends `WM_CLOSE` to the console window, and terminates *every* process that's attached to the console.

Comment: To get a new console, use the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (i.e. new console without a window). To skip attaching to any console, use `DETACHED_PROCESS`. To create a new group, use `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. With the latter, by default Ctrl+C will be disabled in the child if attached to a console; it can be enabled manually via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, (ish) I had use a subtle variation `p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, cmd], **pkwargs)`.

Works on python 3.6.x as well.

Comment: If the script runs in SSH, you may also want `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`. It acts like `nohup` in Linux.

Comment: "With the latter, by default Ctrl+C will be disabled in the child if attached to a console; it can be enabled manually via SetConsoleCtrlHandler"
Can you elaborate - How do I enable it?